# Socket event is repeated more than once

Tags: javascript, socket.io, angular-socket-io

I am using Angular-socket.io. I have an event inside

```
mySocket.on('endquestion' , function(){
   doSomething();
})
```

The problem is the `endquestion` is called many times that's why the event is called many times. How can I limit that to only one instance?

Comment: how do you send the event?

Comment: i send the event in my "host" client here it is.

 mySocket.on('allFinished',function(){
  
   mySocket.emit('endQuestion' , localStorage.getItem('active_room') 

 });

Comment: does the number of declaration of the angular socket io factory causes that?

Comment: Are you sure thereis only one host?

Comment: i have 4 controllers with a declaration of the angular socket io factory.

Comment: Yes i am sure. I am  the only one using this. Im just testing stuffs. Thanks for the effort btw.

Comment: Dont you think the problem is the multiple declaration of angular socket io factory per controller? Im new to this i am sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Use the .once() method:

```
mySocket.once('endquestion' , function(){
  doSomething();
})
```

Comment: this doesnt fix the problem. the event is just triggered 1 time. I want it to be triggered again for the next event i will make. Thanks btw man.